# Magento2 : How I can add Date of Birth field to customer address

Tags: magento2, checkout, attributes, customer-attribute

As per Magento default **"Date of birthday"** is display in **customer registration** form. I want to show it on **customer address** form in checkout step.

Any way to display it on **customer address** form. I don't show it on registration, It should display only on checkout customer address.

Will I need to create new customer address attribute** or use existing "**Date of birthday"** customer attribute ?

**Thanks.**

Comment: Brother, i don't understand why u need D.O.B as a custom attribute for Customer Address. Apart from all that, if u want to accomplished which u asked above, u have to add `Custom Customer Address Attribute` progamitically. Also, in `Magento` there are more than one address so ur custom address attribute will also be too.

Answer (score 3):

Actually currently not possible by default.
It's tracked here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14509

Meanwhile you could do this on your own:

[Magento 2 - How to add a custom field to checkout and then send it](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135969/magento-2-how-to-add-a-custom-field-to-checkout-and-then-send-it)

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_form.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Configuration → Customers → Cusotmers Configuration → Name and Address Options
```

Show Date of Birth and Show Gender, it will show in checkout page and customer registration page.

Comment: You're right about that it shows these options on the registration page, but I don't see them on the checkout

Comment: The answer is partially true but not relevant for the checkout