# Magento 2 checkout - add a custom field between shipping address and shipping method

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, custom-field

I'm trying to add a custom field in between the **shipping address** and **shipping method** sections. And I want values of this field to be stored in both `quote` and `sales_order` tables ultimately. This is something similar to adding an "order comment" field but this field should appear right after the shipping address section and before the shipping method section.

I went through Magento dev guides on how to add a [custom field](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html) and a [custom form](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_form.html) to the checkout and implemented a solution to a certain extent.

What I have done so far:

1. Updated the `checkout_index_index.xml` layout, added a new `uiComponent` (a container) under the item "shippingAddress".
2. Added the element (field) I require inside the container.
3. Override the `/js/view/shipping.js` and `shipping.phtml`in my custom module.
4. Invoked the above made container inside `shipping.phtml` in between checkout shipping address and shipping method (something similar to adding a new static form)

Now the field I want is being rendered on the onepage checkout exactly where I want. But I have met with below problems.

1. How to access the value of the custom field I have added above? I'm trying to save the value to a shippingAddress extension attribute. I added a mixin to `setShippingInformationAction` inside that try to do the below

   `shippingAddress['extension_attributes']['custom_field'] = shippingAddress.customAttributes['custom_field'];`

But above code actually fails since the element is not in the `shipping-address-fieldset`. I might be able to get the value through the `window` element. But is there a way to access this through Magento?

2. Is there a way to save the value of this element in local cache storage (`Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data`) so the value will persist even after a page refresh?

Comment: Take a look on this - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135969/magento-2-how-to-add-a-custom-field-to-checkout-and-then-send-it

Comment: Please refer below link i hope it will help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187847/how-to-add-custom-fields-to-checkout-page-in-magento2/187848

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question I'm under the assumption you already have your extension attributes set up. I have carried out a similar modification and hopefully my answer helps.

In your Custom module create a requirejs-config file to extend the default shipping processor/default

```
Namespace/CustomModule/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default': 'Namespace_CustomModule/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default'
        }
    }
};
```

Add your extension attribute to the payload.

```
/*global define,alert*/
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'ko',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/resource-url-manager',
        'mage/storage',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment-service',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/method-converter',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/error-processor',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-billing-address'
    ],
    function (
        $,
        ko,
        quote,
        resourceUrlManager,
        storage,
        paymentService,
        methodConverter,
        errorProcessor,
        fullScreenLoader,
        selectBillingAddressAction
    ) {
        'use strict';

        return {
            saveShippingInformation: function () {
                var payload;

                if (!quote.billingAddress()) {
                    selectBillingAddressAction(quote.shippingAddress());
                }
                //Adding the extension attributes to your shipping address
                payload = {
                    addressInformation: {
                        shipping_address: quote.shippingAddress(),
                        billing_address: quote.billingAddress(),
                        shipping_method_code: quote.shippingMethod().method_code,
                        shipping_carrier_code: quote.shippingMethod().carrier_code,
                        extension_attributes:{
                            custom_field: $('#custom_field').val(), 
                        }
                    }
                };

                fullScreenLoader.startLoader();

                return storage.post(
                    resourceUrlManager.getUrlForSetShippingInformation(quote),
                    JSON.stringify(payload)
                ).done(
                    function (response) {
                        quote.setTotals(response.totals);
                        paymentService.setPaymentMethods(methodConverter(response.payment_methods));
                        fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
                    }
                ).fail(
                    function (response) {
                        errorProcessor.process(response);
                        fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
                    }
                );
            }
        };
    }
);
```

Save the Attribute to your Quote with a plugin (Not sure if you could use an observer here I have not checked).

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement">
        <plugin name="Namespace_CustomModule_save_delivery_date_in_quote" type="Namespace\CustomModule\Plugin\Checkout\SaveAddressInformation" />
    </type>

</config>
```

SaveAddressInformation.php

```
class SaveAddressInformation
{
    protected $quoteRepository;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository
    ) {
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    }
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject
     * @param $cartId
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
     */
    public function beforeSaveAddressInformation(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject,
        $cartId,
        \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
    ) {
        $extensionAttributes = $addressInformation->getExtensionAttributes();
        $customField = $extensionAttributes->getCustomField();
        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
        $quote->setCustomField($customField);

    }
}
```

Save the Attribute to your order with an Observer 
events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before">
        <observer name="unique_observer_name" instance="Namespace\CustomModule\Observer\SaveCustomFieldToOrder"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

SaveCustomFieldToOrder.php

```
class SaveCustomFieldToOrder implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_objectManager;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager)
    {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
    }

    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getOrder();
        $quoteRepository = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository');
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
        $quote = $quoteRepository->get($order->getQuoteId());
        $order->setCustomField( $quote->getCustomField() );

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Overriding core methods is not too lucky. What if another module override yours?

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135969/magento-2-how-to-add-a-custom-field-to-checkout-and-then-send-it/136316

Comment: good point, was not aware of the alternate method. thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @vaso123 It looks like I am also not aware of something because here Nathaniel has created a plugin and one event-observer so which core function is overriden here. Could you please explain it little more, it would be really helpful ... Thanks

Comment: @Sarvagya When you use require js, do not use `map *`, use mixin instead.

Comment: @vaso123  I believe he is referring to   
 Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default': 'Namespace_CustomModule/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default'  which as Ii understand replaces  Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default.
        }   its been a while since I wrote this so Sarvagya  please correct  me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes. But what if another plugin uses that `Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default`?

This is why I sad, mixin is a better solution, where you can call origigan method after or befor your code:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a plugin for this
`\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor::process` method.

Make an entry in di.xml on this path

```
app/code/CompanyName/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml
```

Create plugin class on this Directory.

```
app/code/CompanyName\Module\Model\Plugin\Checkout
```

2 => Create plugin class on this Directory.
 `app/code/CompanyName\Module\Model\Plugin\Checkout`

```
    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
    ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['custom_field'] = [
        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
        'config' => [
            'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
            'template' => 'ui/form/field',
            'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input',
            'options' => [],
            'id' => 'custom-field'
        ],
        'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes.custom_field',
        'label' => 'Custom Field',
        'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
        'visible' => true,
        'validation' => [],
        'sortOrder' => 250,
        'id' => 'custom-field'
    ];


    return $jsLayout;
}
```

}

Once this is done, check the checkout page.