# How to add custom filed with custom step in magento2 checkout?

Tags: magento2, checkout

I want to add custom step checkout step with  tile "Prescription"

with one custom form where four radio button is present and selecting those radio button save in ***custom table*** when order placed

i know how to create custom step in checkout but i don't know how to save data with ***custom table***

in magento2

Comment: you can try with place order observer.

Comment: but how to set in checkout quote js data

Comment: Please check with this - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135969/magento-2-how-to-add-a-custom-field-to-checkout-and-then-send-it i hope its work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use an extension

There is a lot out there but this will do the job and as time of answer is only 99 dollars

https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-checkout-custom-field-extension.html

You will spend a lot more time and money trying to customise the checkout yourself.

It is painful to do in m1 and it is painful to do in m2.