# How to add DOB field in checkout page and phone number field in Registration page?

Tags: magento2

How to enable DOB in the checkout page below the first name and last name and phone number field in Registration Page. I have checked so many threads in StackExchange. Still, I didn't get any proper solution.

In the backend, I have enabled DOB and telephone number field. DOB field showing only in registration page not in checkout page.

I have tried to create a custom field that is also not working. Please help me to find out a solution for this.

customer_account_create.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="form_additional_info_customer" template="Canisys_Register::additional.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

InstallData.php

```
<?php
 /**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Canisys\Register\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
* Install data
* @codeCoverageIgnore
*/
class InstallData implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface
{

  /**
   * CustomerSetupFactory
   * @var CustomerSetupFactory
   */
  protected $customerSetupFactory;

  /**
   * $attributeSetFactory
   * @var AttributeSetFactory
   */
  private $attributeSetFactory;

  /**
   * initiate object
   * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
   * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
   */
  public function __construct(
      CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
      AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
  )
  {
      $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
      $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
  }

  /**
   * install data method
   * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
   * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
   */
  public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
  {

      /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
      $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

      $customerSetup->removeAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'mobile_number');

      $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
      $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

      /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
      $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
      $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);
      /**
       * customer registration form default field mobile number
       */
      $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'mobile_number', [
          'type' => 'varchar',
          'label' => 'Phone Number',
          'input' => 'text',
          'required' => true,
          'visible' => true,
          'user_defined' => true,
          'sort_order' => 1000,
          'position' => 1000,
          'system' => 0,
      ]);
      //add attribute to attribute set
      $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'mobile_number')
          ->addData([
              'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
              'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
              'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit'],
          ]);

      $attribute->save();

  }
}
```

additional.phtml

```
<div class="field mobile_number required">
<label class="label" for="mobile_number">
  <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Mobile Number')) ?></span>
</label>
<div class="control">
   <input type="text" name="mobile_number" id="mobile_number" value="" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Mobile Number')) ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}">
</div>
```

I have used this code to add mobile number field in registration page. But its not working.

Comment: easy to add, show here that you have tried

Comment: Try this.. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135969/magento-2-how-to-add-a-custom-field-to-checkout-and-then-send-it

Comment: @SohelRana. I have added the code. Please check.

Comment: You want to add new mobile number field on registration page ? In default Magento if you'll check there is already one field called 'telephone'. Please review that.

Comment: I want to show the telephone number filed in the registration page. I have enabled telephone number field in the backend. It is showing only in the address checkout page not in register page.